# "Pattern expected" in OCaml pattern matching with variants

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, variant

When trying to compile the following snippet:

```
type 'a frame = Empty | Frame of string * 'a * 'a frame

let rec searchFrame f s = match f with
  | Empty -> None
  | Frame(x, val, fr) -> if x == s then
                           Some(val)
                         else
                           searchFrame fr s;;
```

I get an error `Error: Syntax error: pattern expected.` at the second match case, corresponding to `val`. I can't figure out what am I doing wrong here: basically `val` should correspond to a value of type `'a`, but I am instead asked to place a pattern. How can I solve this?

Comment: val is an ocaml keyword... change to sth else

Comment: That solved it! You could post it as an answer so that I can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`val` is an Ocaml keyword - just modify your code by changing `val` by `v` for instance.